# How to make any sense of religion and dead gods in Baldur's Gate 3?

Tags: video-games, dungeons-and-dragons, forgotten-realms

In the previous games of Baldur's Gate, the central main story is that the god Bhaal is dead and his powers are scattered among his semi-mortal children. This is *central* to the lore of those games. Less important to the game, the god Myrkul was dead too.

Baldur's Gate 3 supposedly taking place around 100 years later and now we suddenly have Bhaal and Myrkul worshippers everywhere. In fact those gods are now apparently alive and kicking, for reasons unexplained. As evident in the end of Act 2 in the game where you confront a trio wielding the divine powers of Bhaal, Myrkul and Bane. Powers they supposedly wouldn't have if the gods were dead.

Additionally, the recurring bad guy Sarevok makes a reappearance in BG3 which is consistent with BG2 since he was actually resurrected by the protagonist there, as part of the Bhaalspawn conflict. And now he worships Bhaal, who he clearly ought to know is a dead god, since that was the very premise that made it possible for Sarevok to rise from the dead in the first place.

How does this complete inconsistency in the storytelling and game lore make any sense? I'm mostly interested in the in-game lore of Baldur's Gate, but answers addressing the "official" status of these gods as per Forgotten Realms lore are fine too.

Comment: I don't really get why you have an issue with this. Bhaal explicitly had children to come back, and he did. Well, final of ToB suggests otherwise, OK, but was this solar more clever than Bhaal? Apparently not. You can check canonical fate of BG's protagonist aka Abdel Adrian [here](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Abdel_Adrian).

Comment: @Mithoron I don't think "Bhaal comes back" was any of the possible endings in BG2. You either became a god yourself or you rejected it. For Bhaal to come back then protagonist would have died. My issue is that there's an unexplained, elephant-in-the-room-sized gap in the game lore between "Bhaal is dead and it created a massive crisis" to "Bhaal is alive and well and nobody thinks thats strange".

Comment: I *did* say it wasn't in endings. Canonically protagonist died some hundred years later along with another Bhaalspawn and Bhaal came back. Why did they live so long? That's not much of a biggie in a world in which you can even become immortal (not even getting in genes or whatever).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [*Forgotten Realms* wiki entry](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Bhaal):

> With all of his children dead, all of Bhaal's essence was freed, allowing for his resurrection. Bhaal was revived, and reclaimed the murder domain from Cyric. However, the Lord of Murder was no longer a true deity, and was instead a being of quasi-divine status. As with Bane and Myrkul, he was effectively a mortal. In 1492 DR, the city of Baldur's Gate saw a spate of murders by cultists of the Dead Three.

As regards [Myrkul](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Myrkul), the FR wiki seems to indicate that he never entirely died.

> As Myrkul's avatar was slain, just before the majority of his power was transferred to Cyric during his ascension, the last remnants of his energy entered into the Crown of Horns, which was locked away within a vault inside Khelben "Blackstaff"'s tower. The ancient Netherese artifact held what was left of his personality and memories for a decade, after which it reformed its physical form on Toril. By Myrkul's lingering will, the crown transported around Faerûn to a number of hosts, allowing the god to maintain his influence among the mortals, as he ever did, sowing dissent and fear via suggestion and influence. Among those that wore the crown were Aumvor "the Undying" and the Yuan-ti pureblood, Nhyris D'Hothek.

Comment: Ok but Sarevok isn't dead, so that still doesn't make any sense. Even if he was stripped of his powers/bhaalspawn essence, then how come he is alive 100 years later?

Comment: @Amarth: Truthfully, it does seem like they're playing hard and fast with the lore, but I haven't actually played the game yet, so I'm dependent on online searches.

Comment: Well your answer explains a lot, though it still sucks that the player is supposed to know all of this without an in-game explanation... very bad storytelling.